# Useful Source Code Examples of C?

Tags: c

I'm currently delving into learning C and whilst I'm not far into the process, I'd like some examples of fully-functioning windows applications complete with source code that aren't too complicated to study - things like calculator/notepad?

Anybody got any links to where I might find a good few examples beyond the 'converting kgs to stones' or calculating speed from time and distance?

Would certainly help my inspiration. :D

Thanks.

Comment: If you want windows programs I guess you're after C++??

Comment: Only Windows API is supported for C language on Windows. Higher frameworks are either C++ or C#. So, you shouldn't search for C examples, but for Windows API examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not answer exactly what you asked,but ...
Tring to solve some Euler problems is a good way to familiar with the language features.

http://projecteuler.net/

Comment: Thanks for that, I'd forgotten the name of it ^^... I was planning to use that a bit later on, I was hoping for some examples of Windows API programs as corrected by Let_Me_Be to see the workings of a 'useful' application, as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you want examples of existing C projects, browse github/sourceforge.

I wonder though - why do you want to learn C? Seeing as you're new to C, I'm assuming you might actually mean C++.

What background are you coming from and what do you want to achieve? If you want to try some algorithms, pierr's answer is a good one to get used to any language. Also, if you're interested in learning the language detail/algorithms, avoid shiny UI temptation and stick with the command line.

If you're starting programming for the first time, glenn's answer is a good start.

If you're just interested in Windows application development, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708696.aspx) MS tutorial looks like a good start.

If you are moving from another language, look for a specific guide (e.g. [Java to C++](http://www.horstmann.com/ccj2/ccjapp3.html)) to fill you in on the details quickly.

Comment: Hi Bomadeno, I sort of am new to 'software' development, though web development is technically software i suppose... Basically, I know a fair amount of PHP/MySQL(html/css/etc) and am more interested in developing applications and so forth so I'm looking into C/C++ - starting with C. Whenever I look at job adverts for a software developer its fairly common that they will be looking for candidates with experience in both C and C++ amongst other things, and from what I can gather, a lot of the concepts carry over from C to C++, so starting with the lower level language (well, lower than C++)

Comment: and building up to C++ seems like the logical route to take. As far as my understanding of programming concepts goes, I've only being using procedural techniques in PHP and seemed to hit a brick wall when I came to OO, though I've read a lot of critique as to how PHP handles OO and how it isn't the best language *at all* for learning OO concepts, so thats another perk to learning some other languages. I'm also planning to do a degree in Java, starting in the next few months so I should build my knowledge fairly quickly

Comment: C isn't object oriented, so you won't get far learning OO there - C++ is, but it won't force you to use OO like Java. The degree sounds a great way to learn, and seeing as it's going to be Java, why not prepare by learning Java? You can get a head start on the course with the Eclipse IDE, a good textbook like Big Java or Core Java and a sprinkling of Google.

Comment: Yeah, I know C++ features OO, only reason I'm starting with C is so I can start from the "bottom" - or at least as far down as I'd like to go. :) I figured if I learnt C/C++ in some of my spare time and left Java for university I'll be well-versed in the three languages (at least) in 6 years time - the length of the part-time degree in Java. Thanks for the information on Java though, I'll be sure to add one of the books to my shopping list. :D

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple websites with numerous tutorials:

[C programming](http://www.cprogramming.com/)

[C tutor](http://www.freeprogrammingresources.com/ctutor.html)

Also, be sure to look into pointers:

[something on pointers](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm)

Hope this helps